# How to exit after response in nodejs with express?

Tags: node.js, express

This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. Sorry if I made posting mistakes.

I am trying to exit a function after sending a response to prevent continuing through the function.

node -v = v12.6.0

express = ^4.17.1

mongoose = ^5.6.6

```
// handle adding a new book request submission
        addNewBook: function (req, res) {
            var response = null;
            var name = req.body.name.toLowerCase();
            var url = req.body.url.toLowerCase();
            var category = req.body.category.toLowerCase();
            var tags = req.body.tags.toLowerCase();
            // checking if category already exist. if not, make a new category
            Category.find({label: category}).exec(function(err, data) {
                if(err) {
                    response = res.status(400).send({message:'Error finding category.'});
                } else if(data.length === 0) {
                    var newCategory = new Category({label: category, description: '', keywords: ''});
                    newCategory.save(function(err, data){
                        if(err) {
                            response = res.status(400).send({message:'Error saving new category.'});
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
            // checking if book name already exist
            Book.find({name: name}).exec(function(err, data){
                if(err) {
                    response = res.status(400).send({message:'Error validating Book existence'});
                } else if(data.length > 0) {
                    response = res.status(200).send({message:'book name already exist'});
                } else {
                    req.body.name = name;
                    req.body.url = url;
                    req.body.category = category;
                    req.body.tags = tags;
                    // make a new book document
                    var newBook = new Book(req.body);
                    newBook.save(function (err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            response = res.status(400).send({message: 'Error saving new Book.'});
                        } else {
                            response = res.json(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

            return response;

        },
```

Function continues to executes other part of the function code after a return.

I am also getting "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error on node. Im guessing, preventing the function to continue after sending a response will fix this as well?

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: well at any point you make a res.send will stop your function, and no need return at the end

Comment: you can do it like if(err) return res.status.send .... in both handling error

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I've tried removing returns and return res.status.send. Both ways still continues to excute code after res.

Comment: because you are only handling err , will never return if there are no errors you have to send res.status(200).send({message:'success or something else you like'})

Comment: @Nemer Got it to work! I ended up saving res.status.send into a variable and return that variable after I all my query checks are finished.

Comment: You should NOT put an answer into the question.  Questions here are only for questions. If you want to share an answer to your own question that is different than the other answers you got, then post your own ANSWER (that is allowed here).  Please remove your solution from your question.  It does not belong there.

Comment: Also, I don't see how your solution solves the problem anyway.  You still have multiple code paths that can call `res.send()` multiple times.  I'm not going to discuss that further in comments here.  Please remove your solution from the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wasn't aware I could answer my own questions. Yes there are multiple code paths that can call res.send() but my solution doesnt return each res.send() and only returning a single res.send(). Im more than open for better solutions but thats how I got it to work at the moment.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the return value.  It has to do with calling `res.send()` multiple times for the same request.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see, how would you go about res.send() with multiple db queries in one endpoint request?

Comment: Can you show the code for your entire request handler in your question?  What you show now does not exhibit the problem all by itself therefore we can't easily show you how to fix it.

Comment: Yes sure, I'll update my question. how I currently have it works but as you mentioned before probably not the best solution.

Comment: OK, I wrote an answer based on the code you are now showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the flow of your logic. First is that `return` only returns a function. It does not return the function that calls a function or the function that defines a function.

Basically, your code is:

```
Category.find({label: category}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        // ...
        return;
    } else if(/* ... */) {
        // ...
        newCategory.save(function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                // ...
                return;
            }
        })
    }
});

moreStuffDownHere();

// ...
```

Let's rewrite that to not use anonymous functions to make it clear what's really happening

```
function findCallback (err, data) {
    if(err) {
        // ...
        return; // it's obvious that this returns form findCallback()
                // and NOT yourFunction()
    } else if(/* ... */) {
        // ...
        newCategory.save(saveCallback);
    }
}

function saveCallback (err, data) {
    if(err) {
        // ...
        return;
    }
}

function yourFunction () {
    Category.find({label: category}).exec(findCallback);

    moreStuffDownHere();
}
```

So you can now see that you are not calling `return` anywhere in `yourFunction()`.

The second problem is that `Category.find().exec()` is asynchronous. This means it returns immediately and let any code below it run before calling `findCallback()`. To solve the async issue just move `moreStuffDownHere()` inside `findCallback()`.

Therefore, the simplest change to get your program flow working is to move `moreStuffDownHere`:

```
Category.find({label: category}).exec(function(err, data) {
if(err) {
        res.status(400).send({message: 'Error finding category.'});
        return;
    } else if(data.length === 0) {
        var newCategory = new Category({label: category, description: '', keywords: ''});
        newCategory.save(function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                res.status(400).send({message: 'Error saving new category.'});
                return;
            }

            // More stuff down here, that now will only execute if there are no errors
        })
    }
});
```

---

#### Improve program flow

One issue I have with the solution above is that now `moreStuffDownHere` is hardcoded inside the save callback. One way around it is to refactor the entire operation and make it your own internal API:

```
function addNewCategory (category, callback) {
    // callback will be passed status depending on success or failure

    Category.find({label: category}).exec(function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            // ...
            callback('FIND_FAILURE');
            return;
        } else if(/* ... */) {
            // ...
            newCategory.save(function(err, data){
                if(err) {
                // ...
                    callback('SAVE_FAILURE');
                    return;
                }
                callback('OK');
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Now inside `yourFunction()` you can check the result of the entire operation and decide to return or continue:

```
function yourFunction() {
    // ...

    addNewCategory(category, function (status) {
        switch (status) {
            case 'FIND_FAILURE':
                res.status(400).send({message: 'Error finding category.'});
                return;
            case 'SAVE_FAILURE':
                res.status(400).send({message: 'Error saving new category.'});
                return;
        }

        // More stuff down here ...
    });
}
```

---

#### Improvement 2 - Promises

It's possible to make the program flow much easier to read by using Promises along with async/await. For that you need to wrap the operation in a promise. We can use the `addNewCategory` function we wrote above as an example:

```
function addNewCategory (category) {
    // returns a Promise of true/false

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      Category.find({label: category}).exec(function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            // ...
            resolve('FIND_FAILURE'); // you can also use reject if you want
                                     // to use a try/catch flow
            return;
        } else if(/* ... */) {
            // ...
            newCategory.save(function(err, data){
                if(err) {
                // ...
                    resolve('SAVE_FAILURE');
                    return;
                }
                resolve('OK');
            })
        }
      });
   });
}
```

Now the code is slightly easier to follow because it allows you to keep `moreStuffDownHere` where you originally have it without moving it inside another function:

```
async function yourFunction() {
    // ...

    var status = await addNewCategory(category);
    switch (status) {
        case 'FIND_FAILURE':
            res.status(400).send({message: 'Error finding category.'});
            return;
        case 'SAVE_FAILURE':
            res.status(400).send({message: 'Error saving new category.'});
            return;
    }

    // More stuff down here ...
}
```

> Note: Express accepts functions marked as async as routes/middlewares. You just need to call `res.send()` or `next()` as usual

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. I will give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

The error is as a result of your condition. Hence, both code blocks are run resulting in the response being sent twice. To fix this change your code to this below.

```
Category.find({label: category}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        res.status(400).send({message: 'Error finding category.'});
    } else if(data.length>0) {
       //there is no data with that label - Hence, create one
       var newCategory = new Category({label: category, description: '', keywords: ''});
        newCategory.save(function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                //if error
                res.status(400).send({message: 'Error saving new category.'});     
            }else{
                //if item saves
                res.status(200).send({message: 'Item saved'});
            }
        })
    }else{
      //there is a data with that label availble - do something else
        res.status(200).send(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: No, the real problem is that the `return` is inside an inner function (asynchronous is also a problem but the inner function is more fundamental). You are missing a big clue: the comment line at the bottom that says `// More stuff down here, that gets executed instead of existing.`

Comment: @slebetman Yes! You seemed to get this question more than anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

The error you report happens when there are code paths that can send a response more than once.  You get one and only one response per request.  So, calling `res.send()` more than once is one way that you get that error.

Preventing this when you have a number of asynchronous operations requires a bit more work as you have to make sure that all your code is properly sequenced and all error paths are properly terminated (so further processing doesn't happen).  In general, this code is a lot easier to write using promise-based interfaces for your asynchronous operations, but since you aren't using the promise interface on your database, I'll show how you can do it with your existing callback interface.  In generally, it involves a lot of nesting inside of asynchronous callbacks and very careful if/else and `return` around conditionals and errors.

Your code is subject to this error because you are running `Category.find()` and `Book.find()` in parallel.  You don't wait for the `Category.find()` code to finish before doing the book operations.  If the category code causes an error, you will send that error response, but still continue with the book code which will then send its response.  Instead, you need to make sure that if there's an error with the category stuff that you don't run the book code at all.  For the plain callback interface on your database, that means nesting the book code inside a callback from the category code.  To make this simpler to write, I put the category code into it's own function that has one completion callback that we can use to know when its all done.

Here's one way to do it:

```
    // utility function to create category if needed, requires callback
    // to communicate results
    function createCategoryIfNeeded(category, fn) {
        // checking if category already exist. if not, make a new category
        Category.find({label: category}).exec(function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                fn({message:'Error finding category.'});
            } else if(data.length === 0) {
                let newCategory = new Category({label: category, description: '', keywords: ''});
                newCategory.save(function(err, data){
                    if (err) {
                        fn({message:'Error saving new category.'});
                    } else {
                        // category created
                        fn(null, true);
                    }
                })
            } else {
                // category already exists
                fn(null, false);
            }
        });
    }

    // handle adding a new book request submission
    addNewBook: function (req, res) {
        var name = req.body.name.toLowerCase();
        var url = req.body.url.toLowerCase();
        var category = req.body.category.toLowerCase();
        var tags = req.body.tags.toLowerCase();

        createCategoryIfNeeded(category, function(err, created) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).send(err);
            } else {
                // checking if book name already exist
                Book.find({name: name}).exec(function(err, data){
                    if(err) {
                        res.status(400).send({message:'Error validating Book existence'});
                    } else if(data.length > 0) {
                        res.status(200).send({message:'book name already exist'});
                    } else {
                        req.body.name = name;
                        req.body.url = url;
                        req.body.category = category;
                        req.body.tags = tags;
                        // make a new book document
                        var newBook = new Book(req.body);
                        newBook.save(function (err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.status(400).send({message: 'Error saving new Book.'});
                            } else {
                                res.json(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

The error meassage says that, res can be send once it has been send. So returning it along with the response.

```
Category.find({label: category}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({message: 'Error finding category.'});

    } else if(!data) {
        var newCategory = new Category({label: category, description: '', keywords: ''});
        newCategory.save(function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                return res.status(400).send({message: 'Error saving new category.'});     
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: The real problem is this guys code is his conditions. when `if(err)` is true then `else if(!data)` will also be true. so the response is invoked twice

Comment: @Doc-Han Yup i figured my if(!data) is always returning true. That was one of the issue but I ended up saving the res.status.send into a variable and return that once all my query checks are finish.

Comment: Do you think that's a nice way to go about it?

Comment: @Doc-Han The only thing that is problem I can see right now is that I'm always only sending one error. If there are multiple error the existing error response that is on the variable will be overwritten. I could potentially, change the .send({message: ' '}) to .send({message: [ ] }) and append error messages. Then return responseVariable